# JNLP file not updated for different arguments

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm facing several problem with JNLP file. I'm trying to disable Java from caching the JNLP file because everytime I run it, I am passing different `<argument>` to it... however, I can't seems to ether force it to update itself using `<update check="always" policy="always"/>`. I've also tried to set the `Last-Modified` attribute in the http response header and that didn't work either.

The jar remained the same, so I can't really use the `version` attribute to force it to update either...

What is the proper way to either:

1. Disable JNLP file caching
2. Force it to always updates the JNLP file
3. Properly pass in different arguments everytime the JNLP is launch

Here is my JNLP file, note that the `<argument>` can be different whenever it is launch from the web browser, the JNLP file is dynamically generated from the web:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://blah.blah.com/jnlp/jar/*/">
  <information>
    <title>JNLP Launcher</title>
    <vendor>Blah</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.blah.com"/>
    <description>JNLP Launcher</description>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="always" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="https://blah.blah.com/jnlp/jar/LauncherSigned.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.blah.jnlp.Launcher">
    <argument>{"javawebstart" : "isfullofshit"}</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java web start never updates JNLP file content at client machine. But it performance flawlessly if any of the resource is updated.

For example :

if you commented a helper.jar resource in jnlp file hosted on server. web start does not reflect this change to any of the client which already have the jnlp file downloaded before changes you made to server's .jnlp.

```
   <!--jar href="helper.jar"/-->
```

But, if you completely remove the references of classes own by jar file you commented and **recompiled all the resources and redeployed** them.At this time, unexpectedly java web start becomes proactive and reflects all the changes you have made on the server.

Coming to your point: **You are changing your .jnlp file** , which means due to some mystical reasons your changes are not going to reflect to the clients .

**Solution :**

**Approach I(Complex):**

You have to somehow reflect your changes in any of the jar , so web start can pick them up .Here is a rough sketch :

1.Create a new class as a entry point to your application.

2.In this class check the last modified header of your server's .jnlp file.

3.if last modified date is something different than your local jnlp file.Then ,     simple download the jnlp file from server replace with client jnlp.

4.Restart the .jnlp file on the client .

I did this long time ago , but my requirement was simply reload the .jnlp file when application start up.So , didn't checked the last modified headed for .jnlp file.

```
String[] jarSequence= {"demo.jnlp"};
String codebase = "http://localhost:8818/javawsGame/";

DownloadService ds;
try {
ds =
(DownloadService)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.DownloadService");

if (ds != null) {

URL url =
new URL(codebase + jarSequence[0]);
boolean cached = ds.isResourceCached(url, null);

if (cached) {
ds.removeResource(url, null);
}

//setMessage(msgSequence[0]);
//setLoadingResource(jarSequence[0]);
DownloadServiceListener dsl = ds.getDefaultProgressWindow();
ds.loadResource(url, null, dsl);

}
//take a breath
Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);

Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaws path/to/your/demo.jnlp");
exec.waitFor();
System.exit(0);

} catch (Exception e) {

System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
}
```

**Approach II (Simple):**

1.Clean and simple .Introduce a entry point class say "MainClassArgument.java".

2.Point your .jnlp file to this class as main class .

3.Start instance of your main class ,from this class passing the hardCoded argument to your main class

So using this approach , you need to recompile the class every time you want to change the argument.

This will trick the java web start to reflect your changes to clients immediately.

Hope this helps :)

**Note :** In question you asked for disabling java web start cache , this will not help as **.jnlp file is not cached** , It is stored at clients machine. Java Web start documentation never mentioned that it updates the .jnlp file on client side.According to web start , Updates only limited to resource updates nothing else. We have to figure out our own strategy to update out client .jnlp file.